# How can I control multiple input object value in map

Tags: reactjs

this is a sample in code sand box

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-shadow-iiw4p?file=/src/App.jsx

I want to create table that can be added.
However can not control input value.

How can I control multiple input object value in map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code sample you did not call the `setValues()` function. That's why you could not control the input. Here are some modifications to your code:

```
const inputName = (index, event) => {
    let tempValues = [...values];
    tempValues[index].name = event.target.value;
    setValues(tempValues);
  };
```

I hope this code will work now. I have tested it in your codesandbox example also.
here is the link to that: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-water-d74x5?file=/src/App.jsx